# Codename one - lib install in NetBeans

Tags: codenameone

I have downloaded the library for including Toasts in CN1, but I am not sure how to install/add it to NetBeans.

Could you guide me?

Answer (score 3):

Just place the cn1lib file in the lib directory. Right click the project and select the "Refresh Libs" option. The API of the library should now be available to you.

Comment: Which one is it? Inside the "lib" folder I see "CLDC11.jar" and "CodenameOne.jar"

Comment: Place the cn1lib file in that directory next to those jars. Then right click and select refresh libs.

Comment: There is no cn1lib file next to those jars. There is only a ZIP file

Comment: I looked at the project and it seems he doesn't provide a precompiled version. You can just download the project and compile it or file an issue and ask him to upload a precompiled binary. Compiling the project is pretty easy just open the project in NetBeans and select build (assuming the Codename One plugin is installed).